# How to forbid access to certain endpoint for requests out of localhost using KrakenD?

Tags: linux, krakend

I have two endpoints and I want one of them to be accessible by requests from the localhost only. The other one should receive requests from anywhere. In the [Security](https://www.krakend.io/docs/service-settings/security/#restrict-connections-by-host) section of the documentation I found the next configuration:

```
"extra_config": {
  "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-httpsecure": {
    "allowed_hosts": [
      "host.known.com:443"
    ]
  }
}
```

But this is at the root level only. Also, this includes the port, I need to filter for the criteria: "Comes from the localhost?"

Is there a way in which I can meet this requirement? Whether using KrakenD, IPTables, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KrakenD Enterprise solves that for you. But if you are with the Community version, then you can use the [Common Expression Language (CEL)](https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/common-expression-language-cel/) component.

Although it's much more limited than IP filtering (Enterprise) itself, CEL allows you to write pre-conditions before your backends are actually hit.

An example that checks that a request is coming from localhost (IPv6):

```
{
    "endpoint": "/localhost-ipv6",
    "extra_config": {
        "validation/cel": [
            {
                "check_expr": "'127.0.0.1' in req_headers['X-Forwarded-For']"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can adjust the above snippet with the exact value of the `X-Forwarded-For` you are receiving in your environment. To make sure you are testing the right thing, create a test endpoint like the following:

```
{
    "endpoint": "/test-headers",
    "backend": [
        {
            "host": ["http://localhost:8080"],
            "url_pattern": "/__debug/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Start krakend with `krakend run -d -c krakend.json` and then fire a request from inside and outside. You will see in the KrakenD logs the headers. Like:

```
2022/03/15 10:38:26 KRAKEND DEBUG: [ENDPOINT: /__debug/*] Headers: map[Accept-Encoding:[gzip] User-Agent:[KrakenD Version 2.0.0] X-Forwarded-For:[127.0.0.1] X-Forwarded-Host:[localhost:8080]]
```

Finally, there are other ways to solve this with the CEL component. You can even create a pseudo authentication with CEL with something like:

```
{
    "validation/cel": [
        {
            "check_expr": "'acbdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890' in req_headers['X-KEY']"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are more examples in the documentation https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/common-expression-language-cel/